# Java Graphical design loops

Tags: java

```
for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
        for(int k=11; k > i; k--)
        {
                System.out.print("*");

        }
        System.out.print("\n");
}
```

I have the code above which displays a design like this:

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I am wanting to swap it so that it looks like this:

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

I know that I need to use a loop and System.out.print(" ") in some way to leave spaces.

Whats the best approach to use?  I created two separate loops, but with the next line commands this wont work in two loops.  How would I integrate that into one loop?

Comment: What about printing spaces, then n-(the number of spaces you printed) asterisks?

Comment: I forgot to add, I can only use System.out.print("*"), System.out.print(" ") and system.out.print("\n").

Comment: Since this is homework, incorporate another valuable concept in programming: functions. Write a function that prints a character `n` times, for example, `repeat(char c, int times) { ... }`. Then, for each row, you will be calling the function once for spaces, and once for asterisks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second "picture": you'll have to print a variable number of spaces *before* the "*". That can be accomplished by using another loop *before* the loop that prints the "*", and knowing that every time you print a line, the number of spaces printed is incremented by one, and the number of asterisks is decremented by one.

**EDIT :**

Here's a hint, to get you started. Fill-in the blanks (and remove the comments):

```
int delta = /*fill*/;
for (int i = 0; i < /*fill*/; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < /*fill*/; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < /*fill*/; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    delta += /*fill*/;
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: After printing the spaces, is there any command to go back to the top?

Comment: No, you don't go back to the top there, first you print the spaces, then the asterisks, then the line break - and that completes a single line. The outermost loop will take you "back to the top" for you to deal with the next line.

Comment: I like the concept of filling gaps ;)

Comment: @jjczopek I had no choice, I don't want to ruin the OP's homework :)

Comment: So in the code I have above, would i put the added loop inside the first loop or inside of the second loop?

Comment: Leave the loops just the way they are, don't move them around!. Here we have one big, outer loop which contains inside two inner loops, one _after_ the other.

Comment: But this can't work, The first loop is going to complete, then go to the second loop.

Comment: And that's exactly what we want! the two inner loops will execute, one after the other. The first one will print the spaces, the second one will print the asterisks right beside the spaces, and then we print the line break. And off we go to the next line!

Comment: Right, but the second loop is going to complete to the maximum number of spaces, then write the third.  Its going to do the same on every line.

Comment: @Brandon Not if you fill in the correct value--re-read my comment.

Comment: No, you have to take care of that. For each line, you have to use the `delta` variable to control the number of spaces and the number of asterisks. Why don't you give it a try? I have the feeling that you're not trying to fill the missing parts, think about it for a while and you'll be able to solve it. The above method is correct, you just need to make the effort to understand it. I can't help you anymore.

Comment: Ah, once I re-read and really thought about it a few more times it makes a bit more sense.  Got it running!  Whats the purpose of delta though, it's not printed or used anywhere?

Comment: Ah, I did it in a way that didn't need delta.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.format to left pad your string with spaces.

Comment: The OP said that he can only use `System.out.print()`, so `String.format()` is out of the question.

Comment: Sure, but that information was included in the comments, not the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

Do it using a 2-D array!!! Its very simple and efficient that way!!

For the second result:- Put '*' in places if row_no <= column_no (the half matrix above diagonal plus the diagonal elements) else put a space " " in other places. Run this in loops for row and column. Then print the 2-D array row wise.

Comment: You can use code blocks `to indicate a piece of code`. The formatting is also very nice. You can use them by surrounding the text with backticks ( \` ).